# The sky is my owner. Who am I?

Tags: riddle, video-games

> I fight in the battle between *Darkness* and *Light*.
>
> My owner is the *sky*.
>
> I have one *shape*, but I am two *things* at the same time.
>
> If you miss your *body* or your *heart*, be afraid of me.

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer is

> A keyblade from Kingdom Hearts

I fight in the battle between darkness and light

> The whole game is essentially this.  Literally forces of light vs forces of darkness

My owner is the sky

> The main user of the keyblade is Sora, who's name translates to sky.

I have one shape, but I am two things at the same time

> Its both a Key and a sword?  I was unsure of this one.

If you miss your body or your heart, be afraid of me

> Heartless and Nobodies, both missing either body or heart, are common enemies.

Comment: that's the correct answer mate! Of course it is a key and a sword, (key+blade), as you can smash opponents with it or open new worlds during the whole game.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is

> Death

I fight in the battle between darkness and light

> Death is grey, it's not bad nor is it good.

My owner is the sky

> Death could be considered God who we usually believe to live in the sky.

I have one shape, but I am two things at the same time

> Death could be life too

If you miss your body or your heart, be afraid of me

> if you're missing one of the two you usually feel afraid and are going to die.

Comment: please check the assoicated tags for this puzzle. It included video-games as well. Accordingly your answer should be chosen. Good luck !

Comment: oh... I hadn't seen it. My answer is most likely wrong then. I'll remember to check the tags next time I give an answer. Thanks for telling me.

Comment: @Kanta quite a good answer, but as Mea already told you, the answer is related to video-games, and fits perfect with the description, for example, your explanation in the first point is pretty far from the description... the color grey has nothing to do with a battle!

Answer (score 0):

Considering games  tag, maybe you're a:

> War (form Darksiders). This also could be any of 3 others horsemen (Death which was mentioned before as an answer, but not exactly in that way. Or Strife or Fury).

Cause:

I fight in the battle between Darkness and Light.

> Well, the whole plot is about heaven and hell divided and you're fighting sort of between them.

My owner is the sky.

> basically all 4 horseman came from the 'sky'.

I have one shape, but I am two things at the same time.

> He's nor angel, nor a human. Though he;s exists in same form being summoned on earth.

If you miss your body or your heart, be afraid of me.

> maybe this means people who do not follow 'their heart' and do mean things, along with those who are not humans (armies of hell\heaven, demons, etc.)

*wiki quote:

> War is not aligned to Heaven or Hell but instead serves to bring order by the rule of The Charred Council, whose purpose is to uphold the balance between the two forces.

I know this might not exactly fit, but it's first what came to my mind, and seems pretty logic :)

Comment: lets remark some things that may help you finding the answer: - Coming form the sky, does not mean that the _sky_ is your owner. - The answer is not something that is "_nor_ a human _nor_ an angel" but "a human _and_ an angel" (Angel and human come from your answer, they have nothing to do with the real answer. - The fourth answer is very far from the real answer.

Comment: Okay then, that's interesting. Thanks for pointing out things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Is the game

> Bayonetta

Because:

I fight in the battle between Darkness and Light.

> The plot of the game as an Umbra Witch vs God's creations.

My owner is the sky.

> Bayonetta's father was part of the Lumen Sages, basically opposites to the Umbra Witches. Since Heaven is usually seen as "up above" (the sky), you could say Bayonetta partly belongs to the Sky.

I have one shape, but I am two things at the same time.

> She has the shape of a woman, yet her hair can change into beasts (Gomorrah) and weapons, like fists for example.

If you miss your body or your heart, be afraid of me

> There are Broken Witch Hearts throughout the game, which increases Bayonetta's power if they are collected. So if you miss your heart they are found, and you should be afraid